# Integrate Jquery with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I really want to integrate Jquery along side my asp.net webforms and ajax. I'm not quite ready to move to MVC yet because I need to knock out a few applications quickly. My question is, does anyone have any advice how I can begin integrating jquery with ASP.Net server controls and AJAX. For example:

I have a listview control (with an image icon, and label control) It's databound in code behind to a SQLSERVER database. I would like the user to be able to sort the data (with the options I provide them). I want to do this in an update panel as to prevent a full postback, and I want to use jquery to animate the remaining elements (whether it's a fade or quicksand, etc)

I may be asking a lot, but just trying to figure out if it's possible since the HTML elements don't exist until the page is loaded. I'm also not sure if the JQUERY will have a conflict with the AJAX Control Toolkit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this scenario of rendering data from server side and play with sorting on the client side.

If the entire data is populated in client side. 
Hide the rendered list

1. Show a loading icon
2. Read all the data from HTML and put it as an object array
3. Object will have the properties you wish to sort
4. Sort the object array lookout [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) plugin
5. Render the sorted array with jQuery templates
6. Now further sort will go from step 5 no post back involved

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks good, I'm going to think through this and try it out. I'm not quite sure how I will create the object array yet from html, but I should be able to figure it out. Thanks.